# A small lisp like DSL that gets compiled into C/C++ code -- Antlr a good choice?

Tags: c++, c, antlr, dsl

Creating a Lisp syntax like DSL - very small specific application - but very fast - code generation in C, Antlr a good choice?

It is necessary for many reasons that it be very fast and it will internally call a lot of C++  APIs, hence I cannot write it in a language other than C/C++.

The last time I did something in compilers was in school around 5 years ago in flex/bison.

This time however, I have to write production ready maintainable code for this task. I've been looking into Antlr for quite a while and it seems good. But I've the following concerns:-

- Is support for C/C++ target good?
- Is Antlr suitable for building a Lisp syntax like DSL?
- Overall, will it be better than using flex/bison for this particular application?

Also, if you could let me know what topics/parts of Antlr I should be really good at then it would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR is good when your syntax is complex.

LISP syntax is not complex, by design.  Everything is pretty much handled by two grammar rules:

```
sexp  = identifier | number | string | '(' sexps ')' ;
sexps = empty | sexps sexp ;
```

Its such a simple lexer and parser that you can easily implement this as a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) (in C or
in any other language; older LISPs implement this in LISP so they can implement LISP interpreters and compilers directly in LISP).

You can use ANTLR for this, but I think its overkill.   If your language is actually more complex than you suggest, then ANTLR may be a good choice.

Building a good DSL usually requires a LOT more than just parsing.  See my essay on "Life After Parsing" (via bio) for more details.